# Facebook Login on my website: "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Tags: facebook

I am trying to implement Facebook Login functionality to my website.  I followed the instructions, and have entered the code correctly as far as I can see it.  Here is my code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email" >Login with Facebook</div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
```

If you see something I don't, please let me know.  This should work as far as I can tell (after following facebook's instructions).

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Please update with the script close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're replacing MY_APP_ID with your actual ID, and closing your script section.  If that's not the problem, I'd need to see more of your HTML source besides the snippet you provided.

Here is an example html page source, that has a button to login/logout, depending on whether you're currently logged in or not.  It also displays the logged in users profile pic when logged in.  It's an example I made based on the facebook docs, but I've tested it and it works.  Obviously you'll need to replace the app id with an actual app id.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- Display a login if you're coming to the app from outside of facebook -->
 <div id="login">
 <p><button onClick="loginUser();">Login</button></p>
 </div>

 <div id="logout">
   <p><button  onClick="FB.logout();">Logout</button></p>
 </div>

<script>
   function loginUser() {    
     FB.login(function(response) { }, {scope:'email'});     
   }
</script>

<p>Misc page content here...</p>

<!-- Initialize the fb javascript SDK -->
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({ appId: '1234567...', 
              status: true, 
              cookie: true,
              xfbml: true,
              oauth: true});
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);  
  };
</script>

<!-- Callback triggered when the user authenticates -->
 <script>
  function handleStatusChange(response) {
      document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log(response);

        updateUserInfo(response);
      }
    }
 </script>

<!-- fb javascript SDK import -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
</script>

<!--Display the user's face when they log in -->
<div id="user-info"></div>
 <script>
   function updateUserInfo(response) {
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture">' + response.name;
     });
   }
 </script>

<!-- This style sheet changes the name of the body to reflect logged in status, thereby
     cueing to the login logout buttons which one should be visible -->
<style>
  body.connected #login { display: none; }
  body.connected #logout { display: block; }
  body.not_connected #login { display: block; }
  body.not_connected #logout { display: none; }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, the script close did get cut off, and MY_APP_ID was meant as a placeholder for my actual APP ID (which I enter).

Comment: Joseph, I used your code, and I am getting the same error.  I don't know what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Ok, I entered my home url for the "APP Domain" on the Basics page, and now it just opens and closes immediately

Comment: On your Facebook developer page, and the app settings for this application (corresponding to the API key you're using), have you set up both your "Site Domain" and your "Site URL"?  Those both have to be set up, and match the location of where you put the html page above.

Comment: I looked at my settings again, and for my example above I'm also setting the "Canvas URL" to the url of this html page, and have the "Canvas FBML/iframe" setting set to iframe.  I don't know if that will make a difference or not.

Comment: I have set the "Site Url" to the website the button is on.  I do not see the option of a "Site Domain".  I see "App Domain" (the only thing that has "Domain" in the name on the page).

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the type of app it's set up to be?  Mine is set up with three of the options checked under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook": "Website", "App on Facebook", and "Mobile Web".  The "App on Facebook" setting is the one that gives you the "Canvas URL" option.  I'm not sure that's going to help though.

Comment: Can you describe more of what's happening, and how you're accessing your webpage?

Comment: I want it to be used so a user can login to the site with facebook as opposed to registering directly.  I want to use the information to fill out a profile when they log in.  ALl I have is the website checked, as that's all I want to do.  I don't want to have an app inside facebook.

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out when i was having the same problem. 
You shouldn't have `,` after `oauth:true`. see below

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    oauth      : true, //',' here is causing the problem
});
```